# How do I maintain a MariaDB database

Tags: python, java, mysql, mariadb

How can I go about trimming my MariaDB database? I would like to get rid of all transactions which are more than six years old

Comment: Please restrict yourself to asking one question per question. I have removed your second question as it 1) didn't provide sufficient information and 2) didn't really ask a question. Please post it in a new question, and make sure to provide a [mre] and full error/exception information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that your transactions have a date column you want

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_ NAME WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE < DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL -6 YEAR);
```

backups?